# merge & write two jsonl (json lines) files into a new jsonl file in python3.6

Tags: python, json, merge, jsonlines

Hello I have two `jsonl` files like so:

`one.jsonl`

```
{"name": "one", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": "1"}
{"name": "two", "description": "testDescription2...", "comment": "2"}
```

`second.jsonl`

```
{"name": "eleven", "description": "testDescription11...", "comment": "11"}
{"name": "twelve", "description": "testDescription12...", "comment": "12"}
{"name": "thirteen", "description": "testDescription13...", "comment": "13"}
```

And my goal is to write a new `jsonl` file (with encoding preserved) name `merged_file.jsonl` which will look like this:

```
{"name": "one", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": "1"}
{"name": "two", "description": "testDescription2...", "comment": "2"}
{"name": "eleven", "description": "testDescription11...", "comment": "11"}
{"name": "twelve", "description": "testDescription12...", "comment": "12"}
{"name": "thirteen", "description": "testDescription13...", "comment": "13"}
```

My approach is like this:

```py
import json
import glob

result = []
for f in glob.glob("folder_with_all_jsonl/*.jsonl"):
    with open(f, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as infile:
        try:
            result.append(extract_json(infile)) #tried json.loads(infile) too
        except ValueError:
            print(f)

#write the file in BOM TO preserve the emojis and special characters
with open('merged_file.jsonl','w', encoding= 'utf-8-sig') as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile)
```

However I am met with this error:
`TypeError: Object of type generator is not JSON serializable` I will apprecite your hint/help in any ways. Thank you! I have looked other SO repos, they are all writing normal json files, which should work in my case too, but its keep failing.

Reading single file like this works:

```py
data_json = io.open('one.jsonl', mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') # Opens in the JSONL file
data_python = extract_json(data_json)
for line in data_python:
    print(line)

####outputs####
#{'name': 'one', 'description': 'testDescription...', 'comment': '1'}
#{'name': 'two', 'description': 'testDescription2...', 'comment': '2'}
```

Comment: can you post the contents of the function extract_json ?

Comment: Hey boss, just updated my post with output.

Comment: do you want your output to be in jsonl format or plain json ?

Comment: Yes, jsonl format please. I will have to share this file, so other party doesn't have to do cleaning. Is it possible? Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible that extract_json returns a generator instead of a list/dict which is json serializable
since it is jsonl, which means each line is a valid json
so you just need to tweak your existing code a little bit.

```py
import json
import glob

result = []
for f in glob.glob("folder_with_all_jsonl/*.jsonl"):
    with open(f, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as infile:
        for line in infile.readlines():
            try:
                result.append(json.loads(line)) # read each line of the file
            except ValueError:
                print(f)

# This would output jsonl
with open('merged_file.jsonl','w', encoding= 'utf-8-sig') as outfile:
    #json.dump(result, outfile)
    #write each line as a json
    outfile.write("\n".join(map(json.dumps, result)))
```

Now that I think about it you didn't even have to load it using json, except it will help you sanitize any badly formatted JSON lines is all

you could collect all the lines in one shot like this

```py
outfile = open('merged_file.jsonl','w', encoding= 'utf-8-sig')
for f in glob.glob("folder_with_all_jsonl/*.jsonl"):
    with open(f, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as infile:
        for line in infile.readlines():
            outfile.write(line)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks man. Is it possible to write like in the jsonl format, also without [] wrapped around?

Comment: Works!! Thank you sir. Appreciate your time helping me out :) Take care!

Answer (score 1):

another super easy way to do this, if you don't care about json validation

```sh
cat folder_with_all_jsonl/*.jsonl > merged_file.jsonl
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this actually. You beat me to it, dang it!

Comment: wow, nice. Although I am not good with console commands, this looks pretty nice. Thank you buddy :) Thank you @UltaPitt for your input too heheh